# Kendo Ui TreeView - Getting node data fails in IE8

Tags: kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

I have a treeview bound to a remote service. The service returns JSON and builds the tree; no problem with any of that.

I have a toolbar associated with the tree that allows a user to perform operations on the tree. The actions each toolbar option takes is dependent on data carried in the JSON that provides the datasource for the tree. I grab this data like so:

```
selectedNode = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").select();
item = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").dataItem(selectedNode);
```

This, however, fails on IE8, with the message "This object does not support this action."

I've tried a few variants on this, but so far no go. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What object action is it failing on? From what I recall, IE8 may not fully support the use of data attributes. If so, you are unable to use your code, specifically the use of '.data("kendoTreeView")'. Good luck.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have a problem with the data attributes, but it does seem to have issues with accessing the datasource. For example, this also fails: tree= $("#solution-hierarchy").data("kendoTreeView");
 
 uid = e.node.attributes['data-uid'].value;
 console.log(tree.dataSource);
  item = tree.dataSource.getByUid(uid);

Comment: The datasource makes it to the log, but getByUid fails.

Comment: What version of kendo are you using?

Comment: Version is v2013.1.319